# Animating spans sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

As part of a Simon game, I want to animate(background change using css) the span tags sequentially.

```
  function animateGeneratedPattern(){

  //alert(generatedPattern);//pattern generated randomly in advance.
  var i=0;
  while(i<generatedPattern.length){

    switch(generatedPattern[i]){

      case 1:

        animateRed();
        setTimeout(animateRed,500);
        break;

      case 2:

        animateGreen();
        setTimeout(animateGreen,500);
        break;

      case 3:

        animateBlue();
        setTimeout(animateBlue,500);
        break;

      case 4:

        animateYellow();
        setTimeout(animateYellow,500);
        break;

    }

    i++;
  }

}
```

For each appropriate color, I am using this type of function to toggle between backgrounds:

```
function animateYellow(){

  $("#4").toggleClass("animateYellow");

}
```

I have managed to change the background, but all the spans change color at the same time. What do I change to make it sequential rather than at the same time??

Full Code Here:  http://codepen.io/jpninanjohn/pen/JKoYqR?editors=1010

Comment: You can make a queue and then execute it in the order you place the elements with a timeout. With this mode you save lot of lines and headaches.

Comment: Isn't my implementation of 'generatedPattern' as an array also a queue here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation uses generatedPattern as an array rather than a queue.  To use it as a queue, operate only on element [0], then splice off element [0] before the next iteration.  Each iteration sets up the next iteration *after* it has executed.  For example, try this:

```
function animateGeneratedPattern() {
    function animateNextPattern(lightup) {
        if (!generatedPattern || generatedPattern.length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        switch(generatedPattern[0]) {
            case 1:
                animateRed();
                break;
            case 2:
                animateGreen();
                break;
            case 3:
                animateBlue();
                break;
             case 4:
                animateYellow();
                break;
        }
        if (lightup) {
            // Long delay before turning light off
            setTimeout(function() {
                animateNextPattern(false);
            }, 500);
        }
        else {
            generatedPattern.splice(0, 1);
            // Small delay before turning on next light
            setTimeout(function() {
                animateNextPattern(true);
            }, 10);
        }
    }

    animateNextPattern(true);
}
```

[JSFiddle of this here](https://jsfiddle.net/drc7xzwt/2/) using your CSS and HTML showing the animation working.

Comment: Lovely... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that the `while` loop runs through each of the animation functions almost instantaneously, with the same 500ms delay. Using the same `i` variable, we can stagger those. Here's an updated codepen: http://codepen.io/thecox/pen/ezmVEy?editors=1010

Basically, just update each of the `switch` statements to multiply the delay by the iteration of the loop:

```
setTimeout(animateRed,500 * i);
```

Adjust the delay length, as needed. Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: This kind of works. The problem now is that the transition of the longer timeouts makes that particular span be in the animated state even when the next span is animated. I want each span to be animated and then return to original state before going to next animation of span...

Comment: That's why I mentioned adjusting the delay length, as needed (should be at least as long as the prior animation). To be honest, the activation state for each quarter is so subtle it was really difficult to test my solution, at all. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your while loop will loop through all the numbers instantly. Causing all the timeouts to be on the same time. You'll need to delay your script (probably using something like `setTimeout(function(){--yourfunctionhere--}, 1000);`

sorry I cant do it; on mobile

Comment: So I should delay my while loop using a timeout as well??

Comment: Take a look at the response @ghost_dad gave, its a really good idea.

Answer (score 2):

just make the setTimeouts different values, ie 500, 1000

Or you could try add a .delay(500) before toggleClass

or just use css, transition delay

Comment: Do you mean -  
  $("#4").toggleClass("animateYellow").delay(500);

Comment: no, delay(500).toggleClass() instead. there are many ways to make items sequential. the easiest i think is to make your timeouts different values.